# Is it advisable to call a method in a template expression?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

In Angular 2 is it advisable to use a component method in an expression? For example, I have the following component

```
  export class AreaComponent {

    totalLength: number;
    totalBreadth: number;
    totalheight: number;
    mylocalVar: number;

    totalSqft: number;

    myMethod(): number {
        let totalArea = this.totalLength * this.totalBreadth * this.totalheight;
        let myVar = 0;
        switch (this.mylocalVar) {
            case 0:
                myVar = 8;
                break;
            case 1:
                myVar = 9;
                break;
            case 2:
                myVar = 10;
                break;
        }

        this.totalSqft = totalArea * myVar ;

        return totalArea * myVar;
    }
}
```

I am displaying the value in `area-component.html` like this

```
<label>{{ myMethod() }}</label>
```

Is it advisable to call component method in expression? Alternatively if I use `totalSqft` to display calculation

```
<label>{{ totalSqft }}</label>
```

Here problem is if `totalSqft` is how I call `myMethod()` while value changes on following form elements `totalLength`, `totalBreadth`, `totalheight`, `mylocalVar`?

I am using template driven approach.

Is any alternative solution available for this scenario in template driven approach ?

Comment: I don't understand this part "Here problem is if totalSqft is how I call myMethod() while value changes on following form elements totalLength, totalBreadth, totalheight, mylocalVar?" Can you please elaborate more? How is this related to "template driven approach"?

Comment: It can be just a getter, `get totalSqft()`. The alternative is to use observables for all variables that are used in calculation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to call myMethod() whenever the form elements totalLength, totalBreadth, totalheight, mylocalVar updated . how can i implement in angular 2

Comment: Make totalLength, totalBreadth, totalheight, mylocalVar setters and call `myMethod()` in them.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If i use getter method means `myMethod()` returns `undefined` while getting from api , because  api response doesnt have that property . any alternative for this or can help to find some usefull links to make my `from elements` to `observables` to subscribe changes .

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer finally i solved the problem with (ngModelChange) for the form values thanks

Answer (score 2):

Binding to methods directly is exlicitly discouraged because it can cause several problems.

- The method is called every time Angular2 runs change detection. If the method does some compute-intensive work this can make your application unresponsive.
- If the method returns different results on successive calls (for example an new object instance is returned for every call) change detection throws an error like `Expression has changed after it was checked.

If you are aware of the pitfalls and know how to avoid them, you can use methods in bindings and they will work fine, but because it is so easy to cause troubles it is discouraged in the style guide.

Actually I just tried to find the style guide rule that tells that it's discouraged but couldn't find it.