# Method inside asyncPipe runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm using `asyncPipe` with a `*ngIf` decorator that automatically subscribe/unsubscribe to an Observable that returns an `object` within an `<ng-container>...</ng-container>`.

So far so good, but inside the `ng-container` tag, I want to pass the `object` as an argument to a method `doSomething(object)`.

The issue is that the method runs 5-8 times?

HTML template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user">
   {{  doSomething(user) }} <-- method executes multiple times
</ng-container
```

TypeScript file

```
class Component implements OnInit { 

    user: Observable<User>; 

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user$ = this.userService.getUser(id);
    }

    checkConfigs(object) {
        console.log(object);
    }
}
```

I've tested if the issue is the Observable that executes multiple times, but it runs once. And then thought the code within `ng-container` is the issue, but that also runs once.

The question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284000/is-it-advisable-to-call-a-method-in-a-template-expression) because I'm not asking if its advisable, but how to solve the issue. In practice, this should work. But because of Angulars changeDetection architecture, it doesn't work as expected with Observables, its even pointed out in this article [things you didn't know about the AsyncPipe](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/27/three-things-you-didnt-know-about-the-async-pipe.html) how to solve it by using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it advisable to call a method in a template expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284000/is-it-advisable-to-call-a-method-in-a-template-expression)

Comment: No, the question does not cover my use case, but nice to know.

Comment: the answer of the linked question answers your question:
Methods in your template will run everytime angular runs change detection.

Comment: @Arikael, as mentioned, it's nice to know but did not solve the issue. The solution to this thread did, so please, stop forcing this solution on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the components changeDetectionStrategy to onPush. after that, your doSomething function does not call several times. So basically it calls the function whenever the change is detected so that's why it is calling multiple times, so after changing detection technique that won't happen

Try this:

in your component:

```
class Component implements OnInit { 
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // this line
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved this also by creating a new component (dummy), that takes the view `object` as an argument.