# Getting a MatToolTip value from a function is getting continually called

Tags: angular, material-design, tooltip

I am getting a list of tooltips from a function in my angular project using a function:

```
[matTooltip]="getToolTip('Column name')"
```

For the purpose of this question, lets say the function looks like this:

```
getToolTip(tooltipName)
{
  var date1 = new Date();
  console.log("getToolTip", tooltipName,date1 )
  return tooltipName;
}
```

-- NB: My real getToolTip function is extracting data from an array

This works fine but if I open up the console I can see that this method is being continually called. I would have thought this is only run once?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-256gc3)

Comment: It is a duplicate of this please check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221435/method-inside-asyncpipe-runs-multiple-times/55221600#55221600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush disable default angular change detection in component. But you should manualy control detection change.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Angular Docs

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a matTooltip bug.

Take a test using title

see: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10306